# Parent element event is fireing on click of child element

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a checkbox and PLacing it on myElement. Here is my code.

```
var myCheckBox = document.createElement("input");
    myCheckBox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    myCheckBox.innerHTML = "";
    myCheckBox.setAttribute("id", "myID");
    myCheckBox.onchange = CheckBoxChange;
    myCheckBox.setAttribute("value", title);
    myEle.insertBefore(myCheckBox, myEle.firstChild);
```

NOw onclick of myEle some another event like sorting is happening. SO when check/Unckeck checkbox the paraent element event is also fiering. How to overcome from that.

What I am trying here is

```
function CheckBoxChange(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

But before my trigger reach at `CheckBoxChange` the event of `myEle` get fierd. How I can restrict that event upto `myEle` and it not come to `checkbox`. 
Thanks for help.

Comment: *"But before my trigger reach at CheckBoxChange the event of myEle get fierd."* - Are you saying the event handler on the parent fires before the event handler on the child? How do you bind the event handler to the parent `myEle`?

Comment: stopProp is the right thing to use. provide a snippet if it is not satisfying you

Comment: @nnnnnn `myEle` is table header and I am placing the property sorting. Once `myEle` is created and rendered then I am giving `checkbox`.  so soring is happening first then  `checkBoxChange`  event is firing.

Comment: Can you provide the relevant code?

Comment: @SagarV yes I am using stop propagation. IS there any way I can use it while creating checkBox.

Comment: @nnnnnn you asking for `myCheckBox.onchange ` this line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click on the checkbox that causes a `click` event and a `change` event, both of which bubble up to the container.

In your code, you stop propagation of the `change` event, but not the `click` event. I am guessing that your parent `myEle` has a `click` handler to trigger the sorting you mention.

If you change your checkbox to use a `click` handler instead of `change` that should behave the way you want, as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/wqdcd41p/. (Note that even if you check/uncheck a checkbox via the keyboard a `click` event will still be triggered.)

Comment: Thank you. I got the difference . I will also go with click and change tutorial. working :)

Comment: Note also that it doesn't make sense to set `.innerHTML` on an input element (inputs don't have content).

Comment: YA noted. I will remove that.